# Помогите решить задачу на Python "Квадраты"

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Добрый вечер комьюнити "stackoverflow". Pешаю задачу на питоне, проблема в том что при в воде числа 7 выдаёт 140, а должно 253, но при в воде числа 2 команда выдаёт правильный результат  5.
Вот задача:

У Алисы и Боба есть прямоугольный лист бумаги в клеточку. Они по очереди рисуют квадраты, закрашивая некоторые из клеточек. Алиса рисует квадраты, ориентируя их вдоль сторон листа, а Боб — под углом в 45 градусов. При этом Алиса рисует первый квадрат из одной клеточки, а каждый новый квадрат описывается вокруг предыдущего. Для лучшего понимания смотрите рисунок. Серым цветом на нем нарисовано четыре квадрата Алисы, а коричневым нарисовано 3 квадрата Боба. Всего семь квадратов.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Алиса и Боб вместе нарисовали n квадратов. Напишите программу, которая определит сколько клеточек на листе бумаги будет закрашено.

**Формат входных данных**

На вход подается единственное натуральное число

`n` — количество квадратов, `1≤n≤100`.

**Формат выходных данных**

Выведите одно натуральное число — суммарное количество закрашенных клеточек.

**Методика проверки**

Программа проверяется на 15 тестах. Прохождение каждого теста оценивается в 1 балл. Тесты из условия задачи при проверке не используются.

**Sample Input 1:**

> 7

**Sample Output 1:**

> 253

**Sample Input 2:**

> 2

**Sample Output 2:**

> 5

А вот мой код :

```
n = int(input())

total_cells = 0

for i in range(0, n+1):
    total_cells += i * i

print(total_cells)
```

Comment: А как формула в коде связана с количеством закрашенных квадратов? Видно же, что она неправильнач.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача может быть решена в замкнутой форме. Ни циклов, ни сумм:

```
n = int(input())
k1 = n // 2        # число коричневых квадратов
k2 = (n + 1) // 2  # число серых квадратов
print((16 * 2 ** k1 - 12 * k1 - 16) + (16 * 2 ** k2 - 16 * k2 - 15))
```

Если в коричневом квадрате закрашено *n* клеток, то в ширину он занимает *n/2 + 1* клетку. В описанном вокруг него сером квадрате будут закрашены *4(n/2 + 1 + 1)* клеток. А в описанном вокруг него коричневом квадрате будет закрашено на четыре клетки больше. Имеем

*n<sub>1</sub> = 4*, *n<sub>i+1</sub> = 2n<sub>i</sub> + 12* - реккурентная формула для числа клеток в коричневом квадрате.

Докажем что *n<sub>i</sub> = 8·2<sup>i</sup> - 12*:

*n<sub>1</sub> = 8·2<sup>1</sup> - 12 = 4*,

*n<sub>i+1</sub> = 8·2<sup>i+1</sup> - 12 = 2·8·2<sup>i</sup> - 12 = 2(8·2<sup>i</sup> - 12) + 12 = 2n<sub>i</sub> + 12*.

Количество закрашенных клеток для *k* первых коричневых квадратов равно

*N<sub>k</sub> = 16·2<sup>k</sup> - 12k - 16*. Докажем это:

*N<sub>1</sub> = 16·2<sup>1</sup> - 12·1 - 16 = 32 - 12 - 16 = 4 = n<sub>1</sub>*.

*N<sub>k+1</sub> - N<sub>k</sub> = (16·2<sup>k+1</sup> - 12(k + 1) - 16) - (16·2<sup>k</sup> - 12k - 16) = 16·2<sup>k</sup> - 12 = 8·2<sup>k+1</sup> - 12 = n<sub>k+1</sub>*

Аналогично выводится формула для числа закрашенных серых клеток:

*M<sub>k</sub> = 16·2<sup>k</sup> - 16k - 15*.

В программе выше по этим двум формулам считается ответ.

За одну секунду можно узнать что для *1_800_000* квадратов в ответе будет *270_929* цифр.

> ```
> $ time echo 1800000 | py temp.py | wc -L
> 270929
>
> real  0m1.021s
> user  0m1.012s
> sys   0m0.012s
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Здесь явный ряд. Размер стороны квадратов:
1-2 - 5-6 - 13-14 - 29-30 и так далее. Т.е. для для второго квадрата в паре сторона +1, а для первого квадрата после пары: (последняя сторона предыдущей пары*2 + 1). Например 5 + 1 = 6, следующий 6 * 2+1=13. Кол-во клеток в квадрате со стороной n равно `(n-1)*4`, кроме первого, там просто 1.

```
n = int(input()) # например, 7
s = 0 # здесь будет кол-во клеток
sq = 1 # длина стороны в первом квадрате
pair = True # признак "пары" квадратов (см. выше описание)
for i in range(n): # перебираем квадраты
    if sq == 1:
        s += 1 # добавляем кол-во клеток первого квадрата
    else:
        s += (sq - 1) * 4 # добавляем кол-во клеток 2+ квадрата 
    if pair:
        sq += 1 # длина стороны в следующем парном квадрате
    else:
        sq +=sq+1 # длина стороны в следующем непарном квадрате
    pair = not pair # на каждой итерации переключаем пару
print(s)
```

```
253
```

**Короткая версия:**

```
s, side = 0, 1
for pair in range(int(input())):  # 7
    s += (side - 1) * 4 or 1
    side += side * (pair % 2) + 1
print(s)  # 253
```

Comment: А можно добавить команду input, это обязательно

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответ